# Symfony2 TimeType Field separate hour's and minute's input fields

Tags: php, symfony, time, form-fields, timefield

I want to get two input fields for hours and minutes with the `TimeType` field. 
I also want to set for the input field of time and hour an unique label, placeholder and / or input values. I also want to render each inpult field individually in TWIG, like

```
{{ form_row(form.TimeExtern[####HOUR FIELD####]) }}
{{ form_row(form.TimeExtern[####MINUTES FIELD####]) }}
```

My current code:

```
$builder->add('TimeExtern', 'time', array(
        'input'  => 'timestamp',
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'required' => true,
        'label' => 'Externe Zeit',
        'attr' => array(
            'help_text' => 'Zeitformat: Stunden:Minuten',
            'input_group' => array(
                'append' => '.icon-time',
            )
        ),
    ));
```

This gives me ONE input field for hour **and** minutes together. 
I've already read the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/time.html) but couldn't find a solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `form_div_layout.html.twig` renders the time widget using

```
{{ form_widget(form.hour, vars) }}
{% if with_minutes %}:{{ form_widget(form.minute, vars) }}{% endif %}
{% if with_seconds %}:{{ form_widget(form.second, vars) }}{% endif %}
```

So as far as I can see you would be able to use

```
{{ form_widget(form.TimeExtern.hour) }}
{{ form_widget(form.TimeExtern.minute)) }}
```

And then just add your details (label, placeholder, etc) in the attributes hash like

```
{{ form_widget(form.TimeExtern.hour, {'label': '', 'attr': {'placeholder': '' }}) }}
{{ form_widget(form.TimeExtern.minute, {'label': '', 'attr': {'placeholder': '' }}) }}
```

Comment: Method "hour" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist

Comment: I missed the `single_text` part, this is for the choices.

Comment: So, it's only possible with choise and not with input fields?

Comment: Not directly. The only way I can think of would be to create your won field type using the `TimeType` (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/TimeType.php#L53-L112) as a base for your working.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the hint. I will try it. Maybe you also can help me with my current problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612300/symfony2-multiple-file-upload-with-add-remove-method