# Symfony2 multiple file upload with add / remove method

Tags: php, forms, symfony, templates, file-upload

I tried to upgrade my existing and working single file upload form to a multi file upload with add and remove function. Therefor I used this docu: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype

My Entity is not called tags but attachments.

I can add via Javascript unlimited name + file fields. After adding, I get this exception:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function contains() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Seotool/src/Seotool/MainBundle/Entity/Attachments.php line 232

I also think, that not all in my code is correct while I tried to upgrade to multiple upload function. Maybe someone can help me get all fixed?

That's my current code, starting with my controller, who is generating the form.

```
 /**
@Route(
 *     path = "/taskmanager/user/{user_id}",
 *     name = "taskmanager"
 * )
 * @Template()
 */
public function taskManagerAction($user_id, Request $request)
{

    /* #### NEW TASK #### */

    $task = new Task();
    $attachment = new Attachments();

    $task->getAttachments()->add($attachment);

    $addTaskForm = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task);

    $addTaskForm->handleRequest($request);

    if($addTaskForm->isValid()):

        /* User Object of current Users task list */
        $userid = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('SeotoolMainBundle:User')
            ->find($user_id);

        $task->setDone(FALSE);
        $task->setUser($userid);
        $task->setDateCreated(new \DateTime());
        $task->setDateDone(NULL);
        $task->setTaskDeleted(FALSE);

        $attachment->setTask($task);
        $attachment->setUser($userid);

        $attachment->upload();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($task);

        $em->flush();

        $this->log($user_id, $task->getId(), 'addTask');

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('taskmanager', array('user_id' => $user_id)));

    endif;

    .....
```

This are particular code snippets of my Task.php Entity

```
<?php

namespace Seotool\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="tasks")
 */
class Task {

    ....

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Attachments", mappedBy="task", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $attachments;


....

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->log = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->attachments = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

....

/**
 * Add attachments
 *
 * @param \Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\Attachments $attachments
 * @return Task
 */
public function addAttachment(\Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\Attachments $attachments)
{
    $attachments->addTask($this);

    $this->attachments->add($attachments);
}

/**
 * Remove attachments
 *
 * @param \Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\Attachments $attachments
 */
public function removeAttachment(\Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\Attachments $attachments)
{
    $this->attachments->removeElement($attachments);
}

/**
 * Get attachments
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getAttachments()
{
    return $this->attachments;
}
```

This is my Attachments.php Entity

```
<?php

namespace Seotool\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="attachments")
 */
class Attachments {

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
public $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
public $path;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="attachments")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $User;


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Task", inversedBy="attachments")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="task", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $task;

/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
 */
private $file;

/**
 * Sets file.
 *
 * @param UploadedFile $file
 */
public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $this->file = $file;
}

/**
 * Get file.
 *
 * @return UploadedFile
 */
public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->path
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->path
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    // the absolute directory path where uploaded
    // documents should be saved
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

protected function getUploadDir()
{
    // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
    // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
    return 'uploads';
}

public function upload()
{
    // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
    if (null === $this->getFile()) {
        return;
    }

    // use the original file name here but you should
    // sanitize it at least to avoid any security issues

    // move takes the target directory and then the
    // target filename to move to
    $this->getFile()->move(
        $this->getUploadRootDir(),
        $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName()
    );

    // set the path property to the filename where you've saved the file
    $this->path = $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName();

    // clean up the file property as you won't need it anymore
    $this->file = null;
}




/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Attachments
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set path
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @return Attachments
 */
public function setPath($path)
{
    $this->path = $path;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get path
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPath()
{
    return $this->path;
}

/**
 * Set User
 *
 * @param \Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\User $user
 * @return Attachments
 */
public function setUser(\Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\User $user = null)
{
    $this->User = $user;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get User
 *
 * @return \Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\User 
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->User;
}


/**
 * Set Task
 *
 * @param \Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\Task $task
 * @return Attachments
 */
public function setTask(\Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\Task $task = null)
{
    $this->task = $task;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get Task
 *
 * @return \Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\Task
 */
public function getTask()
{
    return $this->task;
}

public function addTask(Task $task)
{
    if (!$this->task->contains($task)) {
        $this->task->add($task);
    }
}
}
```

This one is my TaskType.php Form Type Class:

```
<?php
namespace Seotool\MainBundle\Form\Type;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

         ....

    $builder->add('attachments', 'collection', array(
        'type' => new AttachmentsType(),
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'delete_empty' => true,
        'by_reference' => false,
    ));
```

This is my AttachmentsType.php Form Type Class:

```
<?php
namespace Seotool\MainBundle\Form\Type;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class AttachmentsType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Dateiname',
        'required' => false,
    ));
    $builder->add('file', 'file', array(
        'label' => false,
        'required' => false,
        "attr" => array(
            "multiple" => "multiple",
        )
    ));
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver
            ->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\Attachments'
            ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'attachments';
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the wrong call when adding your attachment.

Your association between your attachment and task is a `manyToOne` meaning that `attachments needed to be added to a task` but `a task needs to be set on an attachment`.

To sort out your problem your should just change your add attachment call from

```
public function addAttachment(\Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\Attachments $attachments)
{
    $attachments->addTask($this);
    // this should be set not add

    $this->attachments->add($attachments);
}
```

to

```
public function addAttachment(\Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\Attachments $attachment)
{
    $attachment->setTask($this);
    $this->attachments->add($attachment);
}
```

Comment: Ok, the exception is gone. When adding a new task with 2 attachments ( one added with the "Add" Button , so that I have 2 fields to upload attachment) the first attachment is only put into my database. Do you know why?

Comment: Because you are only uploading one file. You need to loop through the added attachments (possibly through `$form->get('attachments')`) and perform your tasks one that (`setTask, `setUser`, `upload`).... I think.

Comment: Isn't it done by Symfony ? I never saw any code snippets with a loop for sotring the multiple files :-/

Comment: To the best of my knowledge Symfony doesn't actually handle multiple file uploads. The multiple file uploads that I have seen use some sort of javascript widget to send each file individually, which would use the same sort of process as above. I could be wrong though. If you can find some tutorials that say otherwise then I will look and try to answer accordingly.

Comment: Maybe you have time for a chat? It's easier than communicate with comments

Comment: Can do. I've got no idea how to go about that though so you'll have to handle that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60461/discussion-between-qoop-and-marvin).